# Machine with Multiple Motors and Fusing?

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors

We have some old machines that I'd like to overhaul the electrical on. They are wired like in the schematic I provided. L1, L2, L3 come from a fused disconnect on the machine with a set of 30A fuses. All the wiring is 12AWG THHN except for the control circuit which is 14 AWG THHN. It is all in one box, on the machine. Is it okay to wire as is without fusing each motor circuit given that the wire and contactors are rated for it? I've read the 430.53 a few times but not sure if it applies or not still...[image]

Comment: Rated for what? The rating should have been for the amperage it is fused for.  Once there is more fuse, you must instead be rated for what the safety cutoff would be as determined by the system that remains. How are you determining that? Another fuse or breaker somewhere else? A power source? What mechanical and thermal implications does the new limit have?

Comment: The power soource is 480V, 3 phase. The fuses in the disconnect are 30A, the contactors are rated for 32A and the 12AWG THHN wire is rated for 30A. Each motor has a thermal overload. Does each motor still need it's own set of fuses?

Comment: As long as it is fused somewhere, it should be alright.  You may need to also check the timing characteristics of the fuses.

Comment: They are class CC fuses. I feel that this is all practical, making the wire and contactors large enough that circuit will be fine until the fuses blow.

Comment: Except now you won't know if it's a motor that's burned out, or the transformer, or which motor. Having been through that a few times, any downstream fuses are good, even if all items aren't separately fused.

Comment: Very true. The transformer is fused but fusing each motor would provide a means of troubleshooting just by seeing where the fuses are blown. The problem in our facility is even on the newer equipment, maintenance just uses 30A fuses for everything, nullifying any benefit of having the motors fused individually... But that is a whole different problem.